# RestKit Mapping array of objects

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, restkit, nscoding

I'm using RestKit to make an API call, but one of my property isn't mapping correctly.

Say I have:

```
// Animal.h
@interface Animal: NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray<Fruit*> favoriteFruits;

@end
```

with implementation:

```
// Animal.h
// This class conforms to NSCoding and correctly implements encodeWithCoder and initWithCoder, no problem
```

I also have a `Fruit` class with similar `NSCoding` stuff:

```
// Fruit.h
@interface Fruit: NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* name;

@end
```

Here's how I set up my mapping:

```
[animalMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
  @"fruits": @"favoriteFruits"
}];
```

When I make a GET request via RestKit, the JSON I get back is something like this:

```
{
  "fruits": [
    {
      "name": "banana"
    },
    {
      "name: "apple"
    }
  ]
}
```

The request was successfully made, but when I check the mapping result, the elements in `favoriteFruits` array in the `Animal` class aren't of type `Fruit` like I expected. They're of type `NSDictionary`. The values on the `NSDictionary` are all correct... I just need to them to be converted automagically to `Fruit` objects...

Not sure if this is relevant, but when I tried this in the debugger:

```
(lldb) po ((Fruit*)myAnimal.favoriteFruits[0]).name
```

I get:

> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: Attempted to dereference an invalid ObjC Object or send it an unrecognized selector.
>       The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Realized I never added a correct relationship to the mapping... What I should have done was:

```
[animalMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
  // Other attributes go here, but not favoriteFruits
}];
```

Then add these lines:

```
RKRelationshipMapping *fruitsRelationship = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"fruits" toKeyPath:@"favoriteFruits" withMapping:animalMapping];
[candidateMapping addPropertyMapping: fruitsRelationship];
```